# How to override parent template's footer in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, overriding, footer

I'm new in Wordpress and PHP and I've tried some stuff to try to override my footer but I can't find the way. My situation is the parent's footer isn't configurable and I don't know how to override it in the child.

**Parent's code**

footer.php (the part I want to modify is inside ***get_template_part( 'template-parts/footer/site', 'info' );***)

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer
 *
 * Contains the closing of the #content div and all content after
 */
?>
        </div><!-- .wrapper -->
    </div><!-- .site-content -->

    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/footer/footer', 'instagram' ); ?>

    <footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">

        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/footer/footer', 'widgets' ); ?>

        <div id="site-generator">
            <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/navigation/navigation', 'footer' ); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/footer/site', 'info' ); ?>
        </div><!-- #site-generator -->

    </footer><!-- .site-footer -->
</div><!-- .site -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

site-info.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The template used for displaying credits
 *
 */
?>

<?php
/**
 * credits hook
 * @hooked footer_content - 10
 */
do_action( 'credits' );
```

template-tags.php

```
<!-- More code before -->

/**
 * Footer Text
 *
 * @get footer text from theme options and display them accordingly
 * @display footer_text
 * @action footer_content
 *
 */
function footer_content() {
    $theme_data = wp_get_theme();

    $default_footer_content = sprintf( _x( 'Copyright &copy; %1$s %2$s. All Rights Reserved. %3$s ', '1: Year, 2: Site Title with home URL, 3: Privacy Policy Link', 'parent-theme' ), esc_html( date_i18n( __( 'Y', 'parent-theme' ) ) ), '<a href="'. esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) .'">'. esc_html( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ) . '</a>', get_the_privacy_policy_link() . $theme_data->get( 'Name' ) . '&nbsp;' . esc_html__( 'by', 'parent-theme' ) . '&nbsp;<a target="_blank" href="' . esc_url( $theme_data->get( 'AuthorURI' ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $theme_data->get( 'Author' ) ) . '</a>' );

    $footer_content =  '
    <div class="site-info">
        <div class="wrapper">';

        $footer_content .= '<div id="footer-left-content" class="copyright">' . $default_footer_content . '</div>';

    $footer_content .=  '
        </div><!-- .wrapper -->
    </div><!-- .site-info -->';

    echo $footer_content;
}
add_action( 'credits', 'footer_content', 10 );

<!-- More code after-->
```

So this ***footer_content()*** function is the one I'm trying to override. In my *functions.php* of my child theme I tried to unhook the 'footer_content' hook to add mine after adding this:

**Child's code**

```
/**
 * Footer (overrided) 
 */

function remove_parent_footer_function() {
    remove_action('after_setup_theme', 'footer_content');
}
add_action('wp_loaded', 'remove_parent_footer_function');

function child_footer_content() {
    $theme_data = wp_get_theme();
    
    $default_footer_content = sprintf( _x( 'Copyright &copy; %1$s %2$s. All Rights Reserved. %3$s ', '1: Year, 2: Site Title with home URL, 3: Privacy Policy Link', 'parent-theme' ), esc_html( date_i18n( __( 'Y', 'parent-theme' ) ) ), '<a href="'. esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) .'">'. esc_html( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ) . '</a>', get_the_privacy_policy_link() . '' );

    $footer_content =  '
    <div class="site-info">
        <div class="wrapper">';

        $footer_content .= '<div id="footer-left-content" class="copyright">' . $default_footer_content . '</div>';

    $footer_content .=  '
        </div><!-- .wrapper -->
    </div><!-- .site-info -->';

    echo $footer_content;
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'child_footer_content');
```

But the result is that 'child_footer_content()' is executed creating a div with the right info on the top of the website, but the parent footer isn't modified and keeps displaying on the bottom.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The `footer_content` function was added to the `credits` action, but you are trying to remove it from the `after_setup_theme` action.

Comment: @Cbroe It works! I read that you needed to use a hook which was called after the paren't hook, so I thought it couldn't be the same. Thanks!